# iPhone - saving current view as image

Tags: iphone

How can I save the current view as an image to Camera roll from my application? Is it possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Found the solution. Might help someone. To save the current view as an image, do the following

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(pictureView.bounds.size);                  

[pictureView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 

UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(viewImage, nil, nil, nil);
```