# How to save image with added UIBeizerPath?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, calayer

I ma trying to save image with my silly drawing ,but when i save the image only original image getting saved.

my expected image is this:
[image]

This is my image saving code:

```
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(_imgShow.image,
                                   nil,
                                   nil,
                                   nil);
```

This is my UIImageView custom class:

```
    -(void)awakeFromNib
{
//    drawingView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:self.bounds];
//    drawingView.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
//    [self addSubview:drawingView];
    clearBeizer=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    [self updateMask];
}
-(void)updateMask
{
    CALayer *maskLayer=[CALayer layer];
    maskLayer.geometryFlipped=YES;
    maskLayer.contents=(id)self.image.CGImage;
    switch (self.contentMode)
    {
        case UIViewContentModeScaleToFill:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResize;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspect;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeCenter:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityCenter;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeTop:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTop;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeBottom:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityBottom;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeLeft:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityLeft;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeRight:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityRight;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeTopLeft:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTopLeft;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeTopRight:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityTopRight;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeBottomLeft:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityBottomLeft;
            break;
        case UIViewContentModeBottomRight:
            maskLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityBottomRight;
            break;
        default:
            break;

    }
    maskLayer.frame=self.bounds;
//    drawingView.layer.mask=maskLayer;
    self.layer.mask=maskLayer;

}
-(void)setImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    [super setImage:image];
    [self updateMask];
}
-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
//    drawingView.frame=self.bounds;
//    drawingView.layer.mask.frame=drawingView.bounds;
    self.frame=self.bounds;
    self.layer.mask.frame=self.bounds;
}
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    startingPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self];

    if (!CGPointEqualToPoint(startingPoint, CGPointZero))
    {
        UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
        [path moveToPoint:CGPointMake(touchPoint.x,touchPoint.y)];
        [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(startingPoint.x,startingPoint.y)];

        CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
        shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor];
        if([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
        {
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 7.0;
        }
        else
        {
            shapeLayer.lineWidth = 5.0;

        }

        shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] CGColor];
        [self.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
        [clearBeizer addObject:shapeLayer];
    }
    startingPoint=touchPoint;

    //    [arrLayer addObject:shapeLayer];
    NSLog(@"Touch moving point =x : %f Touch moving point =y : %f", touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y);
}
```

This is my custom class.

Comment: From what I understand, you are using a custom `UIImageView` subclass that manipulates the **rendering** of the image rather than the image's data itself. Show your custom subclass; make sure the getter for `image` is returning the modified data.

Comment: @JanGreve ok bro wait a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just changing the **rendering** of the image, not the data of the image itself, but then writing that data and expect it to reflect your view's rendering.

You can use [`snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:) and the results from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/746421/iphone-saving-current-view-as-image) do manage what you actually want to archieve.

Answer (score 1):

Here what you need to do is take screen shot of your windows and the once you get screen shot you will get that image. But you will required to do changes according to your requirement. As when you take screenshot of window you will also get navigation bar and tool bar. So you need to take one screen shot and from that take second screen shot to get image without navigation bar and tool bar.
For saving image pl. visit below url:

Here's what i did:

```
- (void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   endPoint = [touch locationInView:self.IBImgView];

   SPUserResizableView *spResizable = [[SPUserResizableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,200)];

   UIView *contentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:spResizable.frame];
   [contentView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

   CAShapeLayer *lines = [CAShapeLayer layer];
   lines.path = self.drawPath.CGPath;
   lines.lineCap = kCALineCapSquare;
   [self.drawPath removeAllPoints];
   lines.bounds = CGPathGetBoundingBox(lines.path);
   lines.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
   lines.fillColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor; /*if you just want lines*/
   lines.lineWidth = 3;
   lines.position = CGPointMake(spResizable.frame.size.width/2.0f-10, spResizable.frame.size.height/2.0f-10);
   lines.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(.5, .5);
   [contentView.layer addSublayer:lines];

   spResizable.contentView = contentView;

   [spResizable hideEditingHandles];    
   [self.view addSubview:spResizable];
   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Save Image

```
- (IBAction)btnSaveTapped:(id)sender {
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(self.IBImgView.image) writeToFile:[self saveDataInDirectory:@"Img1"] atomically:YES];
}


- (NSString *) saveDataInDirectory:(NSString *)strFileName {
NSString *strDocPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *strDirName;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    // Original Image
    strDirName = [strDocPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:kDocOriginalImg];
    if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:strDirName]) {
        [fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:strDirName withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    }
    strDirName = [[strDirName stringByAppendingPathComponent:strFileName] stringByAppendingPathExtension:@"png"];
return strDirName;
```

}

But make sure that your spResizable view is above UIImageView.

[Taking ScreenShot Programmatically](http://iosameer.blogspot.in/2012/09/taking-screenshot-programmatically-in.html)

And if you want to redraw the image with same path and then delete the current path and draw new path you can use [SPUserResizableView](https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView). But for that you need to store data in dictionary for editing.

Hope this will help in solving your problem.