# iOS Signatureview in scrollview gives issues

Tags: ios, swift, gesture

I have a UITableView with t.o.s, the UITableView has a footer with a SignatureView in. The problem is, when I want to draw my signature the scrollview scrolls. How can I make sure that the signature view doesn't pass gestures to the scrollview?

[image: Storyboard]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to listen for `UIView` Touch delegate methods `touchesBegan`, `touchesMoved`, `touchesEnded`

1) Whenever touch begins or moved you have to disable the the `UIScrollView` as like below.

```
   yourScrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

2) When touch ends again enables the `UIScrollView` as like below.

```
   yourScrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39889413/how-to-disable-and-enable-scrollview-on-the-touch-of-uiview-in-objective-c) is the solution for your problem but in Objective-C, You can check for reference.

Answer (score 1):

put this code when there's is a touch down in signature box

```
scrollCustomFieldView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

and put this code when the user touch up the signature box

```
scrollCustomFieldView.isScrollEnabled = true
```