# How to check UIView is nil or not in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am new in iOS and I am facing problem regarding to do validation of view. I have created Signature like view
[How to draw Signature on UIView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660219/how-to-draw-signature-on-uiview), and now I want to do validation by using this code

```
-(IBAction)SavebtnClick:(id)sender
{

    if(drawSignView==nil)
    {
       UIAlertView *alertviewshow =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Pease Sign" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertviewshow show];
    }
    else if (drawSignViewClient==nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertviewshow =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Please Sign" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertviewshow show];
    }
    else
    {

        viewcontroller1 *management =[[viewcontroller1 alloc] initWithNibName:@"viewcontroller1" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:management animated:YES];
    }
}
```

But I am not getting success. Please tell me what I am doing wrong.

[image]

I want to do validation.

[image]

if I have not sign it shows the message.

Please give me suggestion.

Thanks in advance!

I save Image and used condition

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawSignView.bounds.size);
    [[self.drawSignView.layer presentationLayer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    // NSData *postData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1.0);


    // Store the data
    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];


    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 100);
    [defaults setObject:imageData forKey:@"image"];

    [defaults synchronize];


    if(viewImage==nil)
    {
        UIAlertView *alertviewshow =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Pease Sign" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertviewshow setTag:1];
        [alertviewshow show];
    }
```

But it not work because it contain blank image.

Comment: Can you show some more code ?What is the issue with this code?what you want to do exactly, specify clearly.

Comment: Please explain more for this...

Comment: is this Signatureview an instance?

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: @PiyushPatel I want to do validation if Signature view is nil then it shows popup please sign.

Comment: @PiyushPatel on view I am not able to apply any condition. That the problem I am facing.

Comment: can you tell me the reason why you want to validate UIView? and when you validating it, whats the error you got?

Comment: Now as you update the question its clear what you want

Comment: @PiyushPatel It  not goes in if condition when I have not sign it. I am using this code on view to sign http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39660219/how-to-draw-signature-on-uiview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this answer

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawSignView.bounds.size);
    [[self.drawSignView.layer presentationLayer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // NSData *postData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1.0);

    NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((viewImage), 0.5)];
    int imageSize   = imgData.length;
    NSLog(@"size of image in KB: %d ", imageSize/1024);



    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.drawSignViewClient.bounds.size);
    [[self.drawSignViewClient.layer presentationLayer] renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *viewImageClient = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // NSData *postData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(viewImage, 1.0);

    NSData *imgDataClient = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation((viewImageClient), 0.5)];
    int imageSizeClient   = imgDataClient.length;
    NSLog(@"size of image in KB: %d ", imageSizeClient/1024);

    int OCS=imageSize/1024;
    int Client=imageSizeClient/1024;

    if(OCS<3)
    {
        alertviewshow=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Please do Signature " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertviewshow setTag:1];
        [alertviewshow show];
    }
    else if (Client<3)
    {
        alertviewshow=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Please do Signature " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
        [alertviewshow setTag:1];
        [alertviewshow show];
    }
else
{
//Write Your Code....
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.drawSignView.bounds.size, NO, [UIScreen   mainScreen].scale);

 [self.drawSignView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.drawSignView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
 UIImage *signImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

if(signImage)
  {
    //Get Image from sign view Succesfully
  }
 else
 {
   UIAlertView *alertviewshow =[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning!" message:@"Please Sign" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alertviewshow show];
 }
```

Try this code its definatly work.

Comment: [self.drawSignView drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.drawSignView.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];

Answer (score 1):

For that my suggestion is to check `UIImage` rather then `UIView`, That means are you getting the signature image or not. Then you should check like

```
if(singatureImage1 == nil){
}
else{
}
```

And for another signature

```
if(singatureImage2 == nil)
{

}
else{
}
```

And if you getting not nil image without sign it then use [SinatureView](https://github.com/asifalikhokhar/TESignatureView) which will give you nil image if you did't sign it then you can validate it.

If you check the `UIView`(i.e. Your signature view) is nil or not,You will get always not nil view because you have initialized it.